# @ mention script , make it work with div content editable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, contenteditable

This is my at mention script , which works fine with a textarea . However now i want to use a div contenteditable instead for outputing Rich HTML inside . But i just cant figure out what changes do i need to implement in order to make this work perfectly with a content editable.

Please Help Me.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if ('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if ('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function (pos) {
    this.each(function (index, elem) {
        if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
            elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    });
    return this;
};
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var selword;
    var pcw;
    var pcdw;
    var start = /@/ig;
    var word = /@(\w+)/ig;
    var tagid = new Array();
    $("#sparktext").click(function () {
        var content = $(this).val();
        var ty = $("#sparktext").getCursorPosition();
        var firsts = content.substring(0, ty);
        var lasts = content.substring(ty);
        var faryw = firsts.split(" ");
        var falw = faryw.length;
        var lastw = faryw[falw - 1];
        var laryw = lasts.split(" ");
        var firstw = laryw[0];
        selword = lastw + firstw;
        var lenlastw = lastw.length;
        var lenfirstw = firstw.length;
        lenlastw = lenlastw - 1;
        pcw = ty - lenlastw;
        pcdw = ty + lenfirstw;
        var fpcw = pcw - 1;
        var fstr = content.substring(0, fpcw);
        var lstr = content.substring(pcdw);
        var go = selword.match(start);
        var name = selword.match(word);
        if (go == null) {
            $("#display").hide();
            $("#msgbox").hide();
        }

    });
    $("#sparktext").keyup(function () {
        var content = $(this).val();
        var ty = $("#sparktext").getCursorPosition();
        var firsts = content.substring(0, ty);
        var lasts = content.substring(ty);
        var faryw = firsts.split(" ");
        var falw = faryw.length;
        var lastw = faryw[falw - 1];
        var laryw = lasts.split(" ");
        var firstw = laryw[0];
        selword = lastw + firstw;
        var lenlastw = lastw.length;
        var lenfirstw = firstw.length;
        lenlastw = lenlastw - 1;
        pcw = ty - lenlastw;
        pcdw = ty + lenfirstw;
        var go = selword.match(start);
        var name = selword.match(word);

        var dataString = 'searchword=' + name;
        if (go == null) {
            $("#display").hide();
            $("#msgbox").hide();
        }
        if (go.length > 0) {


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/PHP/Konnect/atmention.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".addname", function () {
        var username = $(this).attr('title');
        var old = $("#sparktext").val();
        var musername = "@" + username;
        var fpcw = pcw - 1;
        var fstr = old.substring(0, fpcw);
        var lstr = old.substring(pcdw);
        if (lstr == "") {
            var content = fstr + musername + " " + lstr;
        } else {
            var content = fstr + musername + lstr;
        }
        $("#sparktext").val(content);
        $("#display").hide();
        var curcont = content.length;
        $("#sparktext").focus().setCursorPosition(curcont);
        $("#msgbox").hide();
    });
});
```

Here the id of the content editable is #sparktext .Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i finally fixed it , for anyone who wants to use this feel free to do so

```
 function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
    sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
        caretPos = range.endOffset;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
      var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
      editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
      var tempRange = range.duplicate();
      tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
      tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
      caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
  return caretPos;
}


function setCaretPos(el, sPos)
{
/*range = document.createRange(); 
range.setStart(el.firstChild, sPos);
range.setEnd (el.firstChild, sPos);*/
var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(el, 0);
range.collapse(true);
var nodeStack = [el], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
if (node.nodeType == 3) {
var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
if (!foundStart && sPos >= charIndex && sPos <= nextCharIndex) {
range.setStart(node, sPos - charIndex);
foundStart = true;
}
if (foundStart && sPos >= charIndex && sPos <= nextCharIndex) {
range.setEnd(node, sPos - charIndex);
stop = true;
}
charIndex = nextCharIndex;
} else {
var i = node.childNodes.length;
while (i--) {
nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
}
}
}
selection = window.getSelection(); 
selection.removeAllRanges(); 
selection.addRange(range);
}

$(document).ready(function(e){
var selword;
var pcw;
var pcdw;
var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;
var tagid = new Array();
$("#sparktext").click(function(){
var content=$(this).text();
var ty = getCaretPosition(this);
var firsts=content.substring(0,ty);
var lasts=content.substring(ty);
var faryw=firsts.split(" ");
var falw=faryw.length;
var lastw=faryw[falw-1];
var laryw=lasts.split(" ");
var firstw=laryw[0];
selword=lastw+firstw;
var lenlastw=lastw.length;
var lenfirstw=firstw.length;
lenlastw=lenlastw-1;
pcw=ty-lenlastw;
pcdw=ty+lenfirstw;
var fpcw=pcw-1;
var fstr=content.substring(0,fpcw);
var lstr=content.substring(pcdw);
var go = selword.match(start);
var name= selword.match(word);
if(go==null)
{
$("#display").hide();
$("#msgbox").hide();
}

});
$("#sparktext").keyup(function() 
{
var content=$(this).text();
var ty = getCaretPosition(this);
var firsts=content.substring(0,ty);
var lasts=content.substring(ty);
var faryw=firsts.split(" ");
var falw=faryw.length;
var lastw=faryw[falw-1];
var laryw=lasts.split(" ");
var firstw=laryw[0];
selword=lastw+firstw;
var lenlastw=lastw.length;
var lenfirstw=firstw.length;
lenlastw=lenlastw-1;
pcw=ty-lenlastw;
pcdw=ty+lenfirstw;
var go = selword.match(start);
var name= selword.match(word);

var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;
if(go==null)
{
$("#display").hide();
$("#msgbox").hide();
}
if(go.length>0)
{


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "AJAX FILE GOES HERE",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});
}

return false;
});

$(document).on("click",".addname",function(){
var username=$(this).attr('title');
var old=$("#sparktext").text();
var musername="@"+username+" ";
var fpcw=pcw-1;
var fstr=old.substring(0,fpcw);
var lstr=old.substring(pcdw);
if(lstr=="")
{
var content = fstr+musername+""+lstr;
}
else
{
var content = fstr+musername+"---"+lstr+"---";
}
$("#sparktext").html(content+"&nbsp;");
$("#display").hide();

var curcont=parseInt(content.length);
setCaretPos(document.getElementById("sparktext"),curcont);
$("#msgbox").hide();
});
});
```